# md-autocomplete dropdown overlaps the input when using md-floating-label

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

[image]

When adding `md-floating-label` to angular material's `md-autocomplete`
The dropdown suggestion items are overlapping the input area of the autocomplete.

**Note**: all css used are default

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this? It will be easier for us to understand the problem and help you.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort I needed to add a custom CSS

```
.md-autocomplete-suggestions-container{
    margin-top: 2em;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: For rapid resolution, thanks! But the autocomplete without md-floating-label  show this margin gap...

Answer (score 0):

Don't put floating in input, but put it in common parent element/div of input and drop down.